# Auth0 suggests the wrong username for ADFS connection

Tags: auth0

I have an aurelia app configured to auth against auth0, and our auth0 tenant is configured with a connection to our Azure AD instance (which again redirects auth requests to our ADFS server).

The problem I'm seeing is that auth0 seems to remember the wrong username for the connection.

Here's my user:

```
"upn": "cyxx@domain.com",
"azure_id": "blabla",
"given_name": "Trond",
"family_name": "Hindenes",
"nickname": "cyxx@domain.com",
"tenantid": "1234",
"email": "Trond.Hindenes@domain.com",
```

As you can see, upn and email are not identical, and AzureAD uses the "upn" for logins. Everything works fine, except that auth0 "remembers" my login based my email address, and when it redirects me to azureAD it pre-fills the username field with my email address, not my upn.

So, my question: Is there any way to force auth0 (either in client settings or the javascript lock library) to send the correct attribute (upn) when redirecting users to AzureAD for logging on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, when Lock shows the "last time you logged with" message it uses a `lastUsedUsername` string provided by the server from the [getSSOData](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0js/v7#sso) endpoint as a label to identify the user.

That label is assigned the `user.email` or, if not available, the `user.name`, and cannot be changed. I understand that you are ok with this, but just to be clear you cannot alter it (you can remove the message altogether by setting the [rememberLastLogin Lock option](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v10/customization#rememberlastlogin-boolean-) to `false`).

Now, if you wish to change the value that is sent to Azure AD, you can use `auth.params.login_hint` in the options. You can either put an empty string (to prevent Auth0 to send any hint to Azure AD) or put any value that you want (like the user's `upn`):

```
var options = {
  auth: {
    params: {
      login_hint: '' // or anything you want
    }
  }
}

var lock = new Auth0Lock(..., ..., options);
```

The problem is that, as of now, there's really no good way to get the `upn` value from the user profile. But if you put an empty string Azure AD will show its own list of last used credentials, which might be good enough for your users.

Comment: thanks, that's a reasonable workaround. I'll give it a go!

Comment: Just a comment on "That label is assigned the user.email or, if not available, the user.name, and cannot be changed. ". - I consider this a bug, simply because the message is wrong. I did not log on with my email the last time, I logged on with my upn. In situations where upn and email are not identical, this will be confusing/frustrating for users.

Comment: I'll add an issue for this so that it gets looked at. I guess this is either a corner case or just no one complained about it before. Thanks!